# How to add whitespace between tags in Selenium?

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I was using Selenium to get data from a table on the web page.

I have HTML with structure:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <span>1</span>
          <span>0</span>
          <br>
          <span>
            <span>Good Luck</span>
            <img src="/App_Themes/Resources/img/icon_tick.gif" width="3" height="7">
          </span>
       </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>Nowaday<br></b>
        <p>hook<br>zp</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I using this code to get all values in this table:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lstTable = browser.FindElements(By.XPath("table/tbody/tr"));
foreach (IWebElement val in lstTable)
{
     ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lstTDElement = val.FindElements(By.XPath("td"));
}
```

But it shows result of  like:
`10Good LuckNowadayhookzp`

I want to result like this:

`1 0 Good Luck Nowaday hookzp`

Have whitespace between a tag.

I think should add `&nbsp;` like this:

```
<span>1</span>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<span>0</span>
```

And:

```
<b>Nowaday<br></b>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>hook<br>zp</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try as below :-

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lstTDElements = browser.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
var allTextList = lstTDElements.Select(El => EL.Text).ToList();
string FinalString = allTextList.Aggregate(new System.Text.StringBuilder(), (sb, s) => sb.Append(" "+s)).ToString().Replace("\n", "");
Console.WriteLine(FinalString);
```

**Edited** :- You can also get separate element togethor with `|` separator using `xpath` as below :-

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lstTable = browser.FindElements(By.XPath("table/tbody/tr"));
foreach (IWebElement val in lstTable)
{
     ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lstTDElement = val.FindElements(By.XPath("//td/span | //td/b | //td/p"));
}
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Sorry, but it not working. At `lstTDElements` values was: `10Good LuckNowadayhookzp`.

Comment: @VănLộc ok try using `GetAttribute("textContent")`...See updated answer...In my case both are working fine..

Comment: values `textContent` should be? In HTML is an example, in a real project it has many <tr> tag in the table so you can't only set for `10Good LuckNowadayhookzp`.

Comment: @VănLộc yes offcourse `textContent` equivalent to text. But any way you can use `|` separator with or condition in xpath to get separate element which will gives you all separated text. try with updated answer..:)

Comment: Thanks @SaurabhGaur very much. With your answer was edited, it will create many rows(in a <tr> tag I found about 6000), and I don't know how to arrangement with correct columns. Because each column, data can be null or have many values in this.

Current, I have `lstTable` contains two columns(in real: 10 columns). And `lstTDElement` contains all data nessesary. How to integrated `lstIDElement` to `lstTable` with correct colums. Using `foreach` with condition?

Comment: @VănLộc I think you ask another question regarding this.. because this time I'm not able to give the answer regarding this...:(